# Text flickers while animating on OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, animation

I have an NSView with white text against a black background. The view animates slowly up and down (+/- 10 pixels every 1.5 seconds), and the text visibly flickers while animating. It doesn't flicker a lot, but enough that it's noticeable when trying to read it. I've tried animating both with NSAnimationContext and CABasicAnimation.

This doesn't happen with the exact same design/animation on iOS, just on OSX. It might have something to do with the screen refresh rate, but it's driving me nuts and I figured I'd ask in case there was a simple solution.

Comment: If the view fills its bounds when it draws, have you overridden `-isOpaque` to return true? Is the view layer-backed? (Not sure if that's implied by the use of `CABasicAnimation`.) What does the drawing code look like? Also, what properties specifically are you animating?

Comment: Yep, tried setting `isOpaque` and no improvement. The views are all layer-backed. I'm using a regular old `NSTextField` for the text against a black background `NSView`. And I'm animating `position.y` in the `CABasicAnimation` / a vertical AutoLayout constraint in the `NSAnimationContext`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just happened to start using Facebook's [Pop Animation framework](https://github.com/facebook/pop) in my project, and when I implemented a `POPBasicAnimation` for this animation the flickering seems to have disappeared completely - even for non-bold text.

Answer (score 0):

The effect you describe is even more pronounced if you animate diagonally. I thought it might be diminished if one turned on `shouldRasterize`, but it's not. It feels as if it is to be an anti-aliasing of the narrow strokes of the font as the image animates through non-integer positions during the animation. The effect is curiously diminished if you use bold fonts. Also, the problem appears to be unrelated to the `NSTextField`, because if I take an snapshot of the `NSTextField`, remove the text field, and animate an `NSImageView`, the flickering is still apparent.

Bottom line, the effect is diminished with bold fonts. It feels like there should be an anti-alias feature one could turn off, but it's escaping me at this point.

Comment: Well at least I'm not going crazy. Guess I'll have to get rid of that animation completely.